# I am trying to hide a div after 5 seconds of page load. Why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="pop-up-chat">
    <div id="div1">
        <div class="pop-up-msg regular-text">Hi, How may I help you?</div>
        <div class="triangle-down"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I am targeting the pop-up-chat div and setting 5 seconds delay and hiding the div. What's wrong with it?

```js
export default {
    name: 'PopUpMsg',
    mounted() {
        this.msgShow();
    },
    methods: {
        msgShow() {
            const msg = document.getElementsByClassName('pop-up-chat');

            setTimeout(() => {
                msg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }, 5000);
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of elements not a single element

Comment: @Siddharth I added an answer. Did you get a chance to look into that. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are working with Vue.js, I will suggest you to use `v-show` directive to show and hide the popup.

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      isVisible: true
  },
  mounted() {
    this.poppupShow();
  },
  methods: {
    poppupShow() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isVisible = false;
      }, 5000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="pop-up-chat" v-show="isVisible">
    <div id="div1">
      <div class="pop-up-msg regular-text">Hi, How may I help you?</div>
      <div class="triangle-down"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add new property to data `showPopup` and set it to `true` then change it to `false` within `mounted` hooks

Using `v-show` to show or hide the wanted element [v-if-vs-v-show](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show)

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- binding style -->
    <div :style="{visibility: showPopup ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }"

    <!-- or use v-show directive to show | hide element -->
    <div v-show="showPopup" class="pop-up-chat">
      <div id="div1">
        <div class="pop-up-msg regular-text">Hi, How may I help you?</div>
        <div class="triangle-down"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- The rest of your template -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'PopUpMsg',
  data() {
    return {
      showPopup: true,
    }
  }
  mounted() {
    this.msgShow();
  },
  methods: {
    msgShow() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showPopup = false
      }, 5000)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Or you can create custom directive `v-visible`

```js
<div v-visible="showPopup" />

Vue.directive('visible', function(el, binding) {
    el.style.visibility = Boolean(binding.value) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
});
```

Comment: If I want to display the same div after 5 seconds. how can I do the same?

Comment: @SiddharthGope programmatically on click event or automatically display that div after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

It works this way

```
methods: {
    msgShow() {
        const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        setTimeout(() => {
            msg.style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(() => {
                msg.style.display = 'none';
            }, 10000);
        }, 5000);
    },
},
```

.pop-up-chat {
display : none; //initially
}